# Boost Mersenne Twister / 53 bit precision double random value

Tags: c++, boost

The Boost library has a Mersenne Twister random number generator, and using the Boost Random library I can convert that into a double value.

```
boost::random::mt19937 rng;         // produces randomness out of thin air
                                    // see pseudo-random number generators
boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<> dblvals(0,1);
                                    // distribution that maps to 0..1
                                    // see random number distributions
double x = dblvals(rng);                   // get the number
```

Internally it looks like it is using an acceptance / rejection method to generate the random number.

Since the underlying integer used to create the double is 32-bits, I think this means I get a random number with 32-bits resolution, in other words 32-bits worth of randomness.

The original mt19937ar.c had a function called genrand_res53() which generated a random number with 53-bit resolution (using two 32-bit integers). Is there a way to do this in Boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use boost you can use [`boost::random::mt19937_64`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost.random.mt19937_64) to get 64 bits of randomness.  If you have access to C++11 or higher you can also use [`std::mt19337_64`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) which will also give you 64 random bits.

I will note that per [boost's listing](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) `boost::random::mt19937_64` runs about 2.5 times slower than `boost::random::mt19937` and that is probably mirrored in its standard equivalent.  if speeds is a factor then this could come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what C++ now offers (since 11), there is `mt19937_64` in boost, take a look [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#header.boost.random.mersenne_twister_hpp).